# Using Boost in android ndk with windows

Tags: android, c++, boost, android-ndk, boost-build

I am trying to use boost library with Android ndk in Eclipse with Windows. I tried to follow [this tutorial](http://www.codexperiments.com/android/2011/05/tips-tricks-building-boost-with-ndk-r5/)

I am stuck in the step with "bjam" command in cygwin.

bjam --without-python --without-serialization toolset=gcc-android4.4.3 link=static runtime-link=static target-os=linux --stagedir=android

Error: bjam command not found.

What is bjam? Also I used the boost 1.53 along ndk r8e. Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Android NDK is no longer dependent on Cygwin, so you can build Boost with the NDK from within Windows command prompt (`cmd`).

In order to make `Boost.Build` find the NDK, edit `boost\tools\build\v2\user-config.jam` file and append the following text:

```
import os ;

androidNDKRoot = C:/android-ndk-r8e ; # put the relevant path
 using gcc : android :
     $(androidNDKRoot)/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ :
     <compileflags>--sysroot=$(androidNDKRoot)/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
     <compileflags>-mthumb
     <compileflags>-Os
     <compileflags>-fno-strict-aliasing
     <compileflags>-O2
     <compileflags>-DNDEBUG
     <compileflags>-g
     <compileflags>-lstdc++
     <compileflags>-I$(androidNDKRoot)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/include
     <compileflags>-I$(androidNDKRoot)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/libs/armeabi/include
     <compileflags>-D__GLIBC__
     <compileflags>-D_GLIBCXX__PTHREADS
     <compileflags>-D__arm__
     <compileflags>-D_REENTRANT
     <archiver>$(androidNDKRoot)/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar
     <ranlib>$(androidNDKRoot)/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
         ;
```

Certainly, instead of `c:/android-ndk-r8e` you have to put the right location of the NDK on your PC.

Besides, you can select more recent platform API, instead of `android-9`.

Also note that the NDK supplies several tool-chains, and the above settings point to gcc-4.7. If you prefer to build boost with some other tool-chain, change `arm-linux-androideabi-4.7` to the relevant path.

After you've put the configuration in user-config.jam, open `cmd`, `cd` to the directory where Boost resides, and invoke `bootstrap`. Then invoke `b2` like this (for example):

`b2 --without-python --without-serialization threading=multi link=static runtime-link=static toolset=gcc-android target-os=linux threadapi=pthread --stagedir=android stage`

**UPDATE**: As of 11/2015, older NDK toolchains seem to have issues with the newer Boost versions, causing compiler crash, so consider using a more recent compiler. To do this, just change every 4.7 occurrence in the above script to 4.9. Also, it's worth compiling with a more recent Android API (eg. andoroid-9 -> andoroid-16 or so).

Comment: D:\android_ndk_with_boost\android-ndk-r8e\sources\boost_1_53_0\tools\build\v2>b2
 --without-python --without-serialization threading=multi link=static runtime-li
nk=static toolset=gcc-android4.6 target-os=linux threadapi=pthread --stagedir=an
droid
D:/android_ndk_with_boost/android-ndk-r8e/sources/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/to
ols\gcc.jam:78: in gcc.init from module gcc
error: toolset gcc initialization:
error: provided command 'D:/android_ndk_with_boost/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/ar
m-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++' not foun
d

Comment: @user2508941 What is "toolset=gcc-android4.6"? How did you define that in your user-config.jam? (Use pastebin.com or similar site to put errors.)

Comment: Is that a syntax error... Coz we have in android ndk r8e (4.4.3  4.6   and 4.7)... changed the 4.7 to 4.6 in the code you gave me dude..

Comment: Path is the same except for the change in the 4.7 to 4.6

Comment: @user2508941 First of all, I'd recommend you to try and use the config file I posted as is, and invoke `b2` as in my example. You can't set "toolset=gcc-android4.6" because there's no "android4.6" version in `using` section, so either keep it "toolset=gcc-android" or learn Boost.Build syntax: http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/configuration.html

Comment: @user2508941 As for using gcc4.6 toolchain, you can do this by changing every occurrence of '4.7` to '4.6' in the above user-config.jam. I believe, `gnu-libstdc++/4.7` path also has to be changed to `gnu-libstdc++/4.6`.

Comment: Cool... Did that too.. Except for the 4.6 to be changed to 4.7, the error remains the same dude

Comment: @user2508941 Post your exact user-config.jam, `b2` line and the output to pastebin.com.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HJ7GSQNW contains the error and user-config.jam .. the command is
b2 --without-python --without-serialization threading=multi link=static runtime-link=static toolset=gcc-android target-os=linux threadapi=pthread --stagedir=android...

Comment: @user2508941 Does the following path exist on your PC 'D:/android_ndk_with_boost/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/windows/bin/` ?

Comment: Yes dude.... got that one right it was windows-x86_64... After changing that I got the following error... http://pastebin.com/eByh5cqg

Comment: @user2508941 So, you actually build for x64? Then I'm afraid I hardly can assist you. Anyway, try removing "threadapi=pthread" option from `b2` line.

Comment: Cool... You rock dude!!!! I got the message that 311 targets have been updated... Could you tell me why I had to remove that option??

Comment: @user2508941 For some reason, <threadapi> feature wasn't found. Did it build Boost.Thread at all? You can try adding it explicitly: `--with-thread` and putting `threadapi=pthread` back...

Comment: Nope I got the same issue ... In http://pastebin.com/gXuUV8Ea you can find the result... I hope the command is what you meant

Comment: Um, why didn't you build Boost.Serialization? Is there any problem?

Comment: @ikh Older NDK versions didn't implement `wchar_t`-related routines, that was the problem. I don't know what the status of this issue is in the recent NDK.

Comment: I use android-ndk-r9d. Boost.Serialization seems to be built successfully, but Boost.Context cannot be built: `'armasm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @ikh so they support now wide-char, great news. As for `Context`, I guess the NDK just doesn't have `armasm` util.

Comment: @IgorR. ummm.. I hope we can use all boost feature sometime ><

Comment: When I try this is I get an error:

`boost_1_55_0/tools/build/v2/kernel\modules.jam:258: in modules.import from module modules
error: When loading multiple modules, no specific rules or renaming is allowed`

It seems to not like the fact that there are a bunch of compile options set in user_config.jam.

Comment: Turns out I had space in the path to my NDK, and even putting it in quotes didn't work. Also, the `androidNDKRoot` variable didn't seem to get dereferenced properly, so I just copy-pasted the actual path instead.

Comment: @dadude999 Make sure the syntax is correct (eg. pay attention to the space before semicolon).

Comment: @Tomáš Zato It's your program that crashes NDK's C++ compiler (a lot of complex templates?). Try using a more recent NDK toolchain, it might be less buggy.

Comment: @IgorR. Wow you must be kidding me. What my program? I was compiling **boost** with it, not my program. Also I downloaded NDK in Friday, so I don't think it's outdated.

Comment: @Tomáš Zato Ah, sorry, I thought you use similar script to compile your own apps with boost.build. Anyway, the recommendation is still the same: use more recent toolchain, instead of legacy gcc4.7 (which is supplied with new NDKs for backward compatibility only).