# How to use the build boost libraries in android ndk after building it

Tags: android, boost, android-ndk

I have built the boost libraries after downloading it. Now if I right click on the Project-> Properties-> C/C++ general -> Paths and symbols and add the $(NDK_PATH)/boost,
the files get recognized before building it but when I try to build I get unresolved error. Note that I do not make the Android.mk file in the boost library as shown [here](http://www.codexperiments.com/android/2011/05/tips-tricks-building-boost-with-ndk-r5/)

because I include it in the paths and symbols. Is it wrong??

I followed the step Igor told me in my previous comment
[Using Boost in android ndk with windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667978/using-boost-in-android-ndk-with-windows/17672227#17672227).
I do not have any `$ANDROID_NDK/sources/boost/android` folder as pointed in the codeexperiments link.. Is anything wrong?

I am using the following command:

```
b2 --without-python --without-serialization threading=multi link=static runtime-link=static toolset=gcc-android target-os=linux --stagedir=android stage
```

The error I get is:

```
notice: could not find main target stage notice: assuming it is a name of file to create. don't know how to make <e>stage ...found 1 target... ...can't find 1 target...
```

Android ndk: r8e

Env: Windows 64 bit

Eclipse: Juno 4.2.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Boost in android ndk with windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667978/using-boost-in-android-ndk-with-windows)

Comment: Add 'stage' at the end of `b2` line, so that BoostBuild would copy all the binaries to "stagedir", i.e. to /boost/android in your case.

Comment: Dude I am using the following command............ b2 --without-python --without-serialization threading=multi link=static runtime-link=static toolset=gcc-android target-os=linux --stagedir=android stage ..... The error I get is ......    notice: could not find main target stage
notice: assuming it is a name of file to create.
don't know how to make <e>stage
...found 1 target...
...can't find 1 target...