# Building boost 1.53 for android. Failed to build Boost.Build build engine

Tags: android, c++, boost, android-ndk

I am trying to build boost 1.53 for android. I have installed android sdk and android ndk r8e (64-bit). Then I followed instructions at [this website](https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/Boost-for-Android)

I am using windows7 and I also installed cygdrive. 
The problem is that my installiation fails and gives the error below:

```
$ bash build-android.sh
To follow build in another terminal, please use: tail -F /cygdrive/d/bfa/Boost-f                                                                                                                                                                                               or-Android-master/logs/myst-log-1064.log
Building boost version: 1.53.0
Cleaning: boost_1_53_0
Using AndroidNDKRoot = /cygdrive/c/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8e
Detected Android NDK version 8e (64-bit)
Building with TOOLSET=gcc-androidR8e CXXPATH=/cygdrive/c/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ CXXFLAGS=
Unpacking boost
Performing boost bootstrap
Building Boost.Build engine with toolset ...
Failed to build Boost.Build build engine
Consult 'bootstrap.log' for more details
bash: cd: No such file or directory
ERROR: Patch failure !! Please check your patches directory!
       Try to perform a clean build using --clean .
       Problem patch: /cygdrive/d/bfa/Boost-for-Android-master/patches/boost-1_53_0/boost-1_53_0.patch
```

I searched google for the error but I couldn't find anything. Do anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: But r8e does not use Cygwin and does not understand all these paths...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Boost in android ndk with windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667978/using-boost-in-android-ndk-with-windows)

Comment: It might be worth using a Linux virtual machine for building anything complicated using the NDK.  Complex C++ applications may work better with the Crystax NDK than Google's version, which intentionally elides support for some C++ features.

Comment: The patch at that link is a joke!  It's so sloppily done.  If you look into the patch file, you'll see that the patch for 1.53 has reference to 1.54 files.  Directories are placed inconsistently... basically, I don't expect anything from that repository to work at all.